# why didn't ASCII/utf-8 used 00000000 to represent char 0 or rather any other character

Tags: binary

I mean why value of 0 value in binary is not used by ascii encoding , it would have been used to represent char 0 or anything else why they used it to represent NULL

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modern digital era, character code 0 could have been any useful thing, such as "0" or "A".  The use of character code 0 as "null," has a long history, as far back as [Murray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code#Murray_code) back in 1901.  This had a particular advantage on punched tape, where a fresh tape with no punches in it read as all 0's.  Distinguishing between "0" and no character proved very valuable.  Instead, ASCII prepended all of the binary coded decimal characters for 0-9 with 011 and reserved the first 32 symbols for control characters like null.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the name of the character. SOH is the name of the ASCII character with code 1. It’s just a name.